# Slider between positive and negative values

Tags: flutter, dart, slider, flutter-animation, flutter-custompainter

I'm using **syncfusion_flutter_sliders** package. Is it possible to display a slider where you choose a value between positive and negative? E.g. the default value is 0 - we can go left on the slider and select a value between 0 and -1, or we can go right and select a value between 0 and 1.

I would like the tack to highlight only the left or right side of the thumb.

An example in the screenshot below:
[image]

**EDIT:**

The best answer for this question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75114671/6942599

Comment: The best answer for this question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75114671/6942599